# Cast void pointer to “type” variable or use memcpy?

Tags: c, embedded

I haven’t been able to find an answer for this. Does it matter which of these methods I use in C?

```
int get_int(void *vptr) {
    return *(int *)vptr;
}
```

or

```
int get_int(void *vptr) {
    int i = 0;
    memcpy(&i, vptr, sizeof(int));
    return i;
}
```

It seems to give the same result on my tests but is this equivalent in every case?

Comment: Can you show your test cases?

Comment: It depends on what that pointer points at. If it points at a variable of type `int` which you know is aligned, then the former version is correct and possibly slightly more efficient. If you don't know where the pointer points at, you cannot use the former version.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that the memcpy will work in more cases -- it just requires that the memory being copied from contains data of the appropriate type.  The cast-and-dereference requires that and also requires that the pointer is valid for accessing that type.  On most machines, this (just) requires proper alignment.  The cast also allows the compiler to assume that it does not alias with a value of a different type.

The net result is that the memcpy is perhaps "safer", but also perhaps a bit more expensive.

Comment: I see now. Thank you so much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> but is this equivalent in every case?

No.

`*(int *)vptr` relies on `int` alignment.  If `vptr` does not point to `int` alsigned data, the result is UB.

`memcpy()` does not have than requirement. It "works" as long as the data is not some trap (rare).

Comment: So both do the same as long as if I’m sure the data is int?

Comment: @Alejandro  The issues are 1) if `vptr` can convert to a proper `int*` (it cannot if it does not meet the minimum `int` alignment requirement - example `int *` might only work on even bounadries, but `vptr` is odd) and 2)  It if the _data_ is is not a properly encoded `int` (this 2nd issue is very rare today).  With `memcpy()`, copy of data works well even if the `vptr` pointer is odd.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, it is not equivalent because, believe it or not, not all pointers are the same in all cases (though on x86+ architectures they are).

The cast, however, will work where it is defined.